# Is there a reference of Spark Log4j properties?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I've been trying to find a reference of all the log4j properties for Spark and having a hard time finding it.  I've found a lot of examples where people seen to have pieces of it.  But I'm trying to see if there's a reference somewhere that has all of them.

For my particular use case, I'm writing some code that performs a series of data transformations by firing off a spark-submit job, that can then be used/extended by other users.  I don't need most of what spark spits out by default and it's easy to just set something like log4j.rootLogger=WARN,stdout.  However, there's some useful bits in INFO that would be good to have printed to the screen.  In particular:

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) -
     client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: ****
     start time: 1508185983070
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: ***My tracking URL***
     user: ***User***
```

And even more specifically the tracking URL.  Probably also somewhat due to my limited knowledge of Log4j makes this a bit tough.  I've tried doing something like:

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client=Info
```

But that doesn't appear to be a legit logging property.  Is there a way to only get that piece of info in Spark?  Is there a trick to seeing all the possible logging properties to set?

Thanks!

***Update***

I was able to figure this out.  Most of it was due to me not knowing how log4j.properties works but have a much better handle on it now.

You can set the logger and log level per class, and that persist down to all child classes.

I changed my log4j.properties to look something like this:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.org.apache.spark=false
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop=false
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.org.spark_project.jetty=false
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client=false
```

And that redirects pretty much all Spark on YARN logs to a file (slightly modified from the link Thiago shared).

The key things I was missing...

1) I needed to include log4j.logger.CLASS_NAME, I was missing the log4j.logger bit..

2) Need to have log4j.additivity.CLASS_NAME=false.  Without this it will just log INFO to the default setting.

It's pretty confusing at first but starts to make a bit of sense once you get the pattern down.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you take a look in this article at Hacker Noon:
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-log-in-apache-spark-f4204fad78a

It is a little bit more complex to generate logs in Spark if you want to generate your own logs in Yarn application as Spark Submit.

Comment: Thanks Thiago, this is super helpful.  One challenge I'm already noticing is that the logging is output to console unless I set the root logger.  It doesn't seem to respect the file logging overrides for all the spark noise.  Some of it is yarn stuff too, and part of the problem I'm having is knowing which log setting to adjust to control that.  For example, "INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client" appears on my console.  I tried setting something like log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client=WARN and that doesn't seem to do anything.  Is there a way to tie that out?